# Understanding a "strange" output about a finite sum

Tags: summation, difference-equations

> Input:

```
Sum[HarmonicNumber[k]/k^2, {k, 1, m}]
```

That is

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{m} \frac{H_k}{k^2}$$

> Output

I will attach a screenshot for I don't even know how to write it. And ys, I have tried to copu-paste it as LaTeX and as input command but it does not work.

[image]

Can someone help me in understanding what it does mean?

Comment: Not sure what you need. Are you having problems reading [the documentation of `DifferenceRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote

$$s_m=\sum_{k = 1}^{m} \frac{H_k}{k^2}.$$

The MA output means that $s_m$ fulfills the recursion relation

$$(m+2)^3 s_{m+2}=1+(m+2) \left(2 m^2+6 m+5\right) s_{m+1}-(m+1)^2 (m+2) s_{m}$$
with initial conditions
$$
s_1=1,\quad
s_2=\frac{11}{8}.$$

Comment: Now it's clear! Thank you so much!